# Link two tables in firebase using Id in android studio using Java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

have a problem, I'm working on a university project, I have two tables in firebase, the gallery table that contains the photos of the itinerary and the itinerary table that contains the various itineraries of the users now I have to make sure that the id of the itinerary and the ID of the image so as to have a photo corresponding to each itinerary ì, also created by the same user. I did so:

```
public void addImageItinerary() {
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    referenceDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firestore =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (images != null) {
        StorageReference itineraryRef = storageReference.child("itinerary_image/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + ".jpg");
        itineraryRef.putFile(images).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    itineraryRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            String itineraryId = referenceDb.child("Itinerary").push().getKey();
                            Log.i("itineraryId", itineraryId);

                            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("image", uri.toString());

                            referenceDb.child("Gallery").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+ "/" + itineraryId).setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        // APRO SCHERMATA MAPPA
                                        // openMapFragment();
                                        Toast.makeText(insertImage_fragment.getActivity(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    } else {

                                        //ERRORE
                                        Toast.makeText(insertImage_fragment.getActivity(), "Operation failed. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(insertImage_fragment.getActivity(), task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(insertImage_fragment.getActivity(),"Please add image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjP1I.png)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? If you have an error, what is the message that you get?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have no mistake, only that in the itinerary table, on firebase, I have an id code that I would like to be shown also in the gallery table ... but this is not done

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "in the itinerary table, on firebase, I have an id code that I would like to be shown also in the gallery table". What do you mean by that?

Comment: @AlexMamo I would like to do this(photo), how do I do it?

Comment: So you want to copy a field from a location to another?

Comment: @AlexMamo  yes I already have the class that creates the table with the various attributes, I am missing the link in the method indicated above –

Comment: @AlexMamo so it creates a new one: " 
                                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Itinerary");
                                String itineraryId = ref.push().getKey();
                                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("image", uri.toString());
                                map.put("userId", uid);
                                map.put("photoId", galleryId);
                                map.put("itineraryId", itineraryId);

Comment: @AlexMamo how can I do?